# Horizontal gap between where the tile ends and the door

Tags: concrete, flooring, tiling, gap

[image: gap in floor with leaves]The gap accumulates leaves when someone walks in. I don't know what we should do. The gap is not the same size from east to west, or north to south. My husband is thinking about just getting another piece of trim that's on the floor beneath the door, but I don't know if that will work.

Comment: Please post a picture showing the whole doorway threshhold.

Comment: You will probably want to fill the gap with a transom or filler piece and finish with weather stripping.

Comment: Is this inside or outside?

Answer (score 0):

A gap between flooring and the wall is common, but it's generally thin enough to be completely hidden by the baseboards.  The gap in your photo looks like it's at least two inches wide, though, possibly larger if it extends under the threshold a bit.

Do you have any more of that tile?  The cleanest-looking solution would be to cut several pieces of tile to fill in the space.  A piece of trim may not be the same height, and almost certainly won't blend in visually.

I suspect you'll have to take the threshold off the door to install whatever material you end up using.  You want the edge of the threshold to overlap the flooring by a little bit, and then caulk the joint between them.  Leaves are annoying, but what you *really* have to protect against is water dripping down there, pooling against the wood, and causing the doorframe to rot.

In a pinch, you may be able to replace the threshold with one that extends far enough to cover the gap.  That might be the least attractive looking option, though.